# Назначить аргументы для функции, прикрепляемой через .addEventListener

Tags: javascript, html

Изучаю Javascript по онлайн учебнику: https://learn.javascript.ru/introduction-browser-events

Тема - метод ".addEventListener". В примерах везде метод прописывается либо через анонимную функцию:

```
element.addEventListener('change', function(){});
```

Либо поименованная функция, но без аргументов

```
function summ (){}
element.addEventListener('change', summ);
```

Нигде не прописывается как этим методом назначить поименованную функцию и присвоить ей аргументы Допустим такой пример: Есть кнопка, к которой нужно по клику навесить сложение двух переменных и вывод суммы через alert() что-то вроде следующего:

```
<input id='butt' type='button' value='сложение двух числел'></input>


<script>
    var a = 5
    var b = 6

    butt.addEventListener('click', addition(a, b));

    function addition (addend1, addend2)  {
        var summ = addend1 + addend2;
        alert(summ);
    }
</script>
```

Как заставить все это работать как надо? В данном примере alert просто выскакивает при загрузке страницы.

Бонусный вопрос: Как возвратить имеющиеся EventListener'ы элемента?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
butt.addEventListener('click', function(e){ addition(a, b); });
```

Comment: Сработало, спасибо. Т.е. нужно обязательно использовать "прокси" функцию?